# Run exe from perl with several argument as variables

Tags: perl, arguments, exe

I'm trying to run an exe file in Perl on windows using the system command.

The exe should get several arguments which are all variables. But it fails with the error "Can't spawn" (as well as some other errors)

I tried several ways ( some don’t make any sense )

```
  system ($some_exe, “$PARAM1" “$PARAM2);
  system ($some_exe.“$PARAM1".“$PARAM2);
  @args = ($some_exe, “$PARAM1" “$PARAM2);      
  system(@args)
```

So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put multiple arguments with comma-separated (just an array).

```
system($path, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, ...);
```

See: [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)